# How to get url as observable, so that whenever it changes, I can make possible changes in my code?

Tags: angular

I need to subscribe to url changes in my angular app, I need to manipulate my header component based on url. I have already tried ActivatedRoute.url but it's giving empty url, and also not firing subscribe when url is changing.

Comment: You want to capture the entire url or parameters of url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by injecting the `Router` into a component. I usually do it in the `AppComponent` so it happens globally for my angular site for things like google analytics tracking.

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe(x => {
      // only interested in the NavigationEnd type of event
      if (!(x instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
        return;
      }

      // Do stuff here
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ActivatedRoute` only provides information on the route that corresponds to the component in which `ActivatedRoute` is injected.

Depending on what you exactly want, I suggest one of the following solutions:

- Subscribe on the leaf components, then forward the events to the header with a service used to share a `Subject` between the leaf component and the header
- Best solution according to me: in your header, inject the `Router` and subscribe to the `router.events`

Example:

```
router.events.pipe(
      filter(x => x instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe(x => {
        // Do whatever you want with x.url
    });
```